# Integrals and Sudakov decomposition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Suppose that an arbitrary vector $k^\mu$ is decomposed in the so-called Sudakov basis
$$
k^\mu = k_i \frac{n_j^\mu}{n_{ij}} + k_j \frac{n_i^\mu}{n_{ij}} + k_\perp^\mu
$$
where $n_{ij} \equiv n_i \cdot n_j$ and $n_i\cdot k_\perp = n_j \cdot k_\perp = 0$.
In this definition $n_i^\mu = (1, \vec{n}_i), n_j^\mu = (1, \vec{n}_j)$
and $\vec{n}_i, \vec{n}_j$ are *not* back-to-back.

My question is, how can one show the following
$$
\int d^d k = \frac{1}{n_{ij}} \int dk_i dk_j d^{d-2}k_\perp 
$$
?